# How to open bootstrap modal windows based on a checkbox selection in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dom-events

I have a couple of checkboxes. When a checkbox is clicked, I have to get the id of checkbox and then open a corresponding modal window. How can I do this using Javascript?

I want the method in Javascript and not jQuery..

Comment: What is the reason for not wanting to use jQuery? Also, please post the code you have currently.

Comment: As if you needed a reason not to use jQuery :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, because all Bootstrap Javascript plugins require jQuery as a dependency (see the **Plugin Dependencies** section of the Bootstrap.js API [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)).

Here's a JSFiddle that demonstrates [how to attach an event listener to a checkbox in Javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/2dnbu92j/).

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggleRedModal"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggleGreenModal"/>

<script>
    document.getElementById("toggleRedModal").addEventListener("click", showRedModal);
    document.getElementById("toggleGreenModal").addEventListener("click", showGreenModal);
</script>
```

Unfortunately, if you look in the console, you'll see the error `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery`.